# Storm ui Error: org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [localhost]

Tags: apache, hadoop, real-time, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to set up apache storm on m windows 7 64 bit machine.
My configurations are as follows-

zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
dataDir=C:/Server-Local/zookeeper-3.4.9/data
clientPort=2181
```

storm.yaml

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
  - "localhost"
storm.local.dir: "C:/Server-Local/apache-storm-1.0.3/data"
nimbus.host: "localhost"
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
ui.port: 8090
supervisor.slots.ports:
  - 6700
  - 6701
  - 6702
  - 6703
```

Steps I followed-
1. setting up env variables
2. zkServer.sh start
3. storm nimbus
4. storm supervisor
5. storm ui
6. navigate to URL: localhost:8090/

I'm getting this error as Internal Server error on storm ui:

```
    org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException:
    Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [localhost]. 
    Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs
    (NimbusClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.storm.ui.core$all_topologies_summary.invoke(core.clj:434)
    at org.apache.storm.ui.core$fn__11360.invoke(core.clj:952)
    at
```

nimbus.log has following error

```
    main-SendThread(0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181) o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn 
    [WARN]Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, 
    closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:701)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.
    doTransport (ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361) at org.apache.storm.shade.org.
    apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
    2017-03-13 22:00:10.937 main-SendThread(0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181)o.a.s.s.
    o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection 
    to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to 
    authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

I tried almost all solutions provided on related StackOverflow posts, unfortunately, none of them is working for me. What could be the issue?

Comment: @Storm experts any leads?

Comment: Have you validated zookeeper is up and running? The error indicates storm is trying to talk to zookeeper on localhost:2181 and getting connection refused.

Answer (score 0):

Please try restarting you nimbus machine alone. It doesn't require to restart any processors running in storm or any supervisors, but only storm nimbus.

Or check your hosts entry, you may not have hosts entry in all the storm cluster. If you using DNS server for resolving the hostname, please remove hosts entries and use DNS name in all nimbus.seeds property in storm.yaml file.